# ScrollViewer not working for ListView when added using C# in Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, listview, windows-10-universal

I have added a ListView dynamically and it displays all the data correctly. Now as the amount of data increases I want to allow user to scroll horizontally and not vertically, so I added ScrollViewer property for ListView using the following code

```
myListView = new ListView();
myListView.ItemsPanel = App.Current.Resources["MyItemsPanel"] as ItemsPanelTemplate;
myListView.ItemTemplate = App.Current.Resources["myListTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
myListView.ItemContainerStyle = App.Current.Resources["GenericListViewContainerStyle"] as Style;
myListView.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple;
myListView.Margin = new Thickness(10);

myListView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
myListView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollModeProperty, ScrollMode.Disabled);
myListView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden);
myListView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollModeProperty, ScrollMode.Auto);
```

*ItemsPanel Template*

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="MyItemsPanel">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="0" />
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
    </StackPanel>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Can someone suggest what is wrong here? I want it to work both using Mouse and Touch input. My Current works fine with touch input but I can't scroll when I use mouse pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

I removed following code

```
myListView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
myListView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollModeProperty, ScrollMode.Disabled);
myListView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden);
myListView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollModeProperty, ScrollMode.Auto);
```

And added following code to my ListView

```
mtListView.Style = App.Current.Resources["ListViewStyle"] as Style;
```

**ListViewStyle**

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Enabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
</Style>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

> Now as the amount of data increases I want to allow user to scroll horizontally and not vertically.

To do this, you will need to modify the template of `ItemsPanel` and together enable the `HorizontalScrollMode` of the `ScrollViewer` inside this `ListView`, in XAML it is like this:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

So besides your code for enabling the horizontal scroll mode,  when define this in the code behind, you also need to get the `ItemsStackPanel` using `VisualTreeHelper` for example in the `Loaded` event of your `ListView`:

```
private void myListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var itemstackpanel = FindChildOfType<ItemsStackPanel>(myListView);
    if (itemstackpanel != null)
        itemstackpanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
}

public static T FindChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : class
{
    var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
    queue.Enqueue(root);
    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        DependencyObject current = queue.Dequeue();
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
            var typedChild = child as T;
            if (typedChild != null)
            {
                return typedChild;
            }
            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I already have assigned ItemPanelTemplate to list view in code behind.

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar, OK, point is you need to change the `ItemsStackPanel` inside the `ItemPanelTemplate` to horizontal orientation. Or if you used other panel controls as the item panel, also, it is needed to change the orientation.